# Get "nil" after uploading PDF/Worddocs to application Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip

So, I am building an application where users can create a **Pin** and upload pictures and **PDF/Word.docs** to the **Pin**. It seems like I have done everything to enable those options;

Created methods in the **Pins** model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
    validates :image, presence: true

    has_attached_file :document
    validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }

    end
```

Generated **migration** in the **DB**

```
class AddFileToPin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :pins do |t|
      t.attachment :document

    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :pins, :document


  end
end
```

Then ran `rake db:migrate` to add the few lines for the documents in my **schema**

Now here is the issue (or issues):

I ran `rails console` in my terminal and started to take a look at some of the **Pins** I've created.

ex: `Pin.find(3)` (looking up the 3rd **Pin** I created, with an image and a PDF attached to it)

Here is the output:

```
Pin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "pins".* FROM "pins"  WHERE "pins"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 => #<Pin id: 3, description: "pdf test 2", created_at: "2001-01-01 00:05:13", updated_at: "2001-01-01 00:05:13", user_id: 1, image_file_name: "Screen_Shot_2014-06-25_at_11.45.55_PM.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 45789, image_updated_at: "2001-01-01 00:05:11", document_file_name: nil, document_content_type: nil, document_file_size: nil, document_updated_at: nil>
```

As you can see the PDF's content is "nil". So, I am wondering if it was truly saved or not and if not, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have not explained how you "created" the "Pins I've created". Step us through it. Give us all the information.

Comment: Would you like me to walk you through the coding step to enable document upload?

Comment: if you like... we need you to walk us through what you typed in and/or clicked on when you actually cause the error you see above. Even if it's obvious to you.