# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/documents/original/missing.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, paperclip

I am using **Paperclip** to upload files (PDF and Word docs) to my Rails app. So far everything seems to work. Yet, when I click on the link for to view my pdf file (`<%= link_to "My document", @pin.document.url, target: "_blank" %>`) a new tap open and I get a **Routing Error**: `No route matches [GET] "/documents/original/missing.png"`

Should I include a new route in my **route.rb** file?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  root "pins#index"
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
```

Pin model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :document
    validates_attachment :document, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }

    end
```

Comment: @Nishu thanks. Took a look at the answers looks similar but I have a hard time applying it to my problem. Do you know if I need to change something in the view or add a new route? `<%= link_to "My document", @pin.document.url, target: "_blank" %>`

Comment: It looks like this pin doesn't have a document attached, but you don't check for that before showing a link to it.

Comment: we have to figure out why it doesn't have one first. What did you do... *before* you got to this screen with the problem? Can you step us through it (make no assumptions, tell us everything you do)?

Comment: I will link you to an earlier question I asked, it has more information about my issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740316/get-nil-after-uploading-pdf-worddocs-to-application-rails

Answer (score -1):

I have the similar problem as yours, and got a tip from the below link:

http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=20097

Simply: keep your PDF files under Public folder if possible.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.